# zf2 doctrine2 and Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter using one db connection

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I use doctrine2 with ZF2, some of my libraries work with Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter, others with doctrine2. Now, they connect to database twice. Is it possible to use one db connection in doctrine and standard ZF2 db adapter?

Answer (score 10):

The `DoctrineORM` module accepts a `PDO` resource or a service name where the instance can be located in the service manager instead of the usual connection params.

First step is to create a service factory which retrieves the PDO resource from the `Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter` service

```
<?php
namespace Application\Db\Service;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException;

class PdoResourceFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @param ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     * @return \PDO resource
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $services)
    {
        $dbAdapter = $services->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');

        $pdo = $dbAdapter->getDriver()->getConnection()->getResource();
        if (!$pdo instanceof \PDO) {
            throw new ServiceNotCreatedException('Connection resource must be an instance of PDO');
        }
        return $pdo;        
    }
}
```

Once you have the factory, it's just a case of adding it to the service manager, configuring the db params for `Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter` and telling doctrine to use the existing `PdoResource` from the service manager to connect.

Assuming you did this all in one file, let's say `dbconn.local.php`...

```
<?php
return array (
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
            // include the pdo resource factory
            'PdoResource' => 'Application\Db\Service\PdoResourceFactory',
        ),
    ),
    // db adapter config
    'db' => array(
        'driver'    => 'pdo',
        'dsn'       => 'mysql:dbname=database;host=127.0.0.1',
        'username'  => 'username',
        'password'  => 'password',
    ),

    'doctrine' => array (
        'connection' => array (
            'orm_default' => array (
                'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
                // use the resource from the zend adapter 
                'pdo' => 'PdoResource',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: This is brilliant, not sure why it hasn't been accepted yet.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for posting this as new answer but I am not able to add a comment to Crisp's answer since my reputation is too low because I only registered to stackoverflow for writing this comment:

In the `dbconn.local.php` that Crisp posted be sure to set `dbname` to `null` like in the following snippet:

#### Addition to Crisp's answer:

```
<?php
return array(
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
            // the lazy way of Crisp's PdoResourceFactory:
            'PdoResource' => function (ServiceLocatorInterface $services) {
                $dbAdapter = $services->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');

                $pdo = $dbAdapter->getDriver()->getConnection()->getResource();
                if (!$pdo instanceof \PDO) {
                    throw new ServiceNotCreatedException('Connection resource must be an instance of PDO');
                }
                return $pdo;  
            },
        ),
    ),
    // db adapter config
    'db' => array(
        'driver'    => 'pdo',
        'dsn'       => 'mysql:dbname=database;host=127.0.0.1',
        'username'  => 'username',
        'password'  => 'password',
    ),

    'doctrine' => array (
        'connection' => array (
            'orm_default' => array (
                'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
                // use the resource from the zend adapter 
                'pdo' => 'PdoResource',
                // important addition to Crisp's answer:
                'params' => array(
                    'dbname' => null,
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

#### And now here is why this is important:

When calling

```
$em->getConnection()->getDatabase();
```

on your `EntityManager` without having set the `dbname` to `null` you will get `"database"` as the name of your database because this is the default value which is set by the `module.config.php` of the `DoctrineORMModule` as you can see [here](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/blob/master/config/module.config.php#L40). Setting the `dbname` to `null` will cause your `Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver` which extends `Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\AbstractMySQLDriver` to load the name of the database via `SELECT DATABASE()` from the database itself as you can see [here](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php#L153).

Also not setting the `dbname` to `null` (or to the correct database name) will cause the `schemaInSyncWithMetadata()` function of the `Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaValidator` to always return false since it cannot load the current database setup because it uses the `Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool` which uses the `EntityManager`'s `Connection` which thinks that the database being used is called `"database"`.

So I hope someone can use this information to save some time. I wasted half the day to figure that out.

And many thanks to Crisp again for his answer that saved me a lot of time.