# zendframework 2 table gateway And doctrine 2- is it possible to operate both systems at same time

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

i am using Zendframework 2 . i wonder if it possible to use both table gateway and doctrine 2 in the same application.

below is my configuration. i tried to run it but i noticed that the speed of my application slowed down considrable.

i was wondering if this was beucase there is a conflict between both applications or because i have not configured it properly.

**global PHP file**

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver'         => 'Pdo',
        'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=thetable;host=localhost',
        'driver_options' => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'
                    => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
        ),
),
```

);

**local php**

```
return array(

   'db' => array(
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => 'password',
    ),  


  'doctrine' => array(
    'connection' => array(
      'orm_default' => array(
        'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
        'params' => array(
          'host'     => 'localhost',
          'port'     => '3306',
          'user'     => 'user',
          'password' => 'password',
          'dbname'   => 'thetable'
        )
      )
    )
  ),
);
```

Comment: You could try sharing the connection between zend db and doctrine -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21072177/zf2-doctrine2-and-zend-db-adapter-adapter-using-one-db-connection/21075088#21075088